# Unix ksh syntax errors

Tags: unix, ksh

I have a script that checks the records in a file ($file) and checks if the file exists and stores it either to the existing or missing array.

```
existing[0]=0
missing[0]=0
i=0
j=0
sourcedir=/mydir
fileslist=/mydir/filelisting.txt
fileextension=csv

while IFS='' read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    f="${line}.${fileextension}"

    if [ -s ${sourcedir}/${f} ]
    then
        existing[$i]=${line}.${fileextension}
        echo "${existing[$i]} exists"
        ((i=i + 1))
    else
        missing[$j]=${line}.${fileextension}
        echo "${missing[$j]} does not exist"
        ((j=j + 1))
    fi
done < "$filelist"
```

Apparently when this gets executed in the client's server I get the following errors:

```
myscript.sh: existing[0]=0: not found

myscript.sh: missing[0]=0: not found

myscript.sh: -r: is not an identifier

myscript.sh: bad substitution
```

Is there some portions on my script not compliant to ksh? If yes, greatly appreciate to assist me what should be the proper syntax. Is also there a way to let the errors reflect which line causes the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you *sure* you're using a proper [KornShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KornShell)? More specifically ksh93?

Comment: @user3694537 : The lines `existing[0]=0` &   `missing[0]=0` works fine for me in ksh.

Comment: does your script have a shebang at the top and if so, what is it? [wondering if script is missing shebang and client could be running the script under some other shell]

Comment: I guess the shell becomes different when it's executed through autosys. I've added the shebang line for ksh and finally got it to work